# Error while importing numpy module in python

Tags: python, numpy, import

I am new to python and I am just trying to play around with *numpy* module.

I am getting an error :

```
******Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'******
```

While trying to run a code using *numpy*. I did download *numpy* from *sourceforge.net* but I am still getting same error.

Comment: You need to give more information, how did you install it, where, on what system?  Clearly your python can't find numpy, you need to expand if anyone is to help you figure out what

Comment: In addition to just downloading it, you need to install it, and at it to your path so that python can find it.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Download numpy wheels from this link